# Compiling C code for .NET

Tags: .net, c

How can I compile C code for use in .NET?

There is a game that written in C; how can I convert it to .Net code or use some parts of it?

Comment: Try using proper capitalization and grammar [u != you]. You will get much better responses that way. Also, (source) code is always singular, never plural.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use C code directly within .NET.

You have a couple of options:

1. Compile the C code into a dynamic link library, and use P/Invoke in order to call it from your .NET program.
2. Port the C code to .NET.
3. Wrap the C code using C++/CLI (making a mixed mode assembly), and use these from within your other .NET language of choice.

Comment: Actually, there is a C to CIL compiler.

Comment: @SLaks: Have you ever used it for anything significant?  It failed on me the only times I've tried ;)

Comment: @shaahin: The topic was closed because your question wasn't written very well.  Better written questions get better responses.  As for the best option above - all three have advantages and disadvantages... It's hard to label one as better than the other, at least without more information.

Comment: The only C to .NET compiler I have seen is the Orange C Compiler. @SLaks have you used another?