# Compiling C to use the CLR

Tags: .net, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiling C code for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283730/compiling-c-code-for-net)

I have a bunch of C source code and I want to compile it so it uses the .NET framework. I downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ and chose new CLR project. I then added all my C code, and I tried to compile the files. It said

```
cl : Command line error D8045: cannot compile C file '..\..\..\..\..\Downloads\lzma912\C\XzDec.c' with the /clr option
```

Why can't I compile this?

Comment: IMHO, it is rude to close a question as "exactly duplicate" of a question that itself was closed as "not a real question"!

Comment: +1 to offset the downvoting. This is a reasonable question, in spite of the pre-emptive ranting by the OP. Given the way some folk dump on anything from MS without thinking, I'm sympathetic. But honestly, just editing the rant out was enough, it really didn't deserve a block of down votes as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sometimes, looking to MSDN can clarify the things. You need to force the compiler to treat C files as C++ files. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abb82cy0(VS.80).aspx).

To quote:

*Only C++ source code files can be passed to a compilation that uses /clr. Use /TP to compile a .c file as a .cpp file; see /Tc, /Tp, /TC, /TP (Specify Source File Type) for more information.*

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the [/Tp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55(v=VS.80).aspx) option so VC++ thinks your source file is C++ code instead of C.   In that way you don't have to change your file extension.

Comment: +1, but does VC++ allow implicit casting from a void pointer? That'll cause an error.

Comment: @Mathepic: That's just to get past the first error, no doubt he'll have other errors after.

Comment: At minimum he'll be forced into the C dialect that is the intersection between C++ and C, as modified by the assumptions of building for the CLR. But the first step is to get the compiler to try at all, and the fact that it can only compile C++ for the CLR is a key fact.